# Vertx delayed batch process

Tags: vert.x, vertx-httpclient

How can I process a list of delayed jobs in Vertx (actually
hundreds of HTTP GET requests, to limited API that bans fast requesting hosts)? now, I am using this code and it gets blocked because Vertx starts all requests at once. It is desirable to process each request with a 5-second delay between each request.

```
public void getInstrumnetDailyInfo(Instrument instrument,
                                   Handler<AsyncResult<OptionInstrument>> handler) {
  webClient
    .get("/Loader")
    .addQueryParam("i", instrument.getId())
    .timeout(30000)
    .send(
      ar -> {
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
          String html = ar.result().bodyAsString();
          Integer thatData = processHTML(html);
            instrument.setThatData(thatData);
            handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(instrument));
        } else {
          // error
          handler.handle(Future.failedFuture("error " +ar.cause()));
        }
      });
}

public void start(){
  List<Instrument> instruments = loadInstrumentsList();
  instruments.forEach(
    instrument -> {
      webClient.getInstrumnetDailyInfo(instrument,
            async -> {
              if(async.succeeded()){
                instrumentMap.put(instrument.getId(), instrument);
              }else {
                log.warn("getInstrumnetDailyInfo: ", async.cause());
              }
            });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using a timer to fire events (rather than all at startup).

There are two variants in Vertx,

1. `.setTimer()` that fires a specific event after a delay

   `vertx.setTimer(interval, new Handler<T>() {});`

and
2.  `.setPeriodic()` that fires every time a specified period of time has passed.

```
vertx.setPeriodic(interval, new Handler<Long>() {});
```

`setPeriodic` seems to be what you are looking for.

You can get more info from the [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_executing_periodic_and_delayed_actions)

For more sophisticated Vertx scheduling use-cases, you can have a look at [Chime or other schedulers](https://vertx.io/blog/time-scheduling-with-chime/)  or [this module](https://github.com/diabolicallabs/vertx-cron)

Comment: thanks, but it seems you got half of the problem, my problem is not scheduling itself, is scheduling batch process with a delay between each job completes

Comment: One idea is to add a hook on the `onComplete()` method of the handler, such that when a handler completes, the next call is made. Is that a possible solution to your use-case?

Comment: it could not help, because this way all of requests will send sequential but we want controlled parallelism

Comment: I'm still pretty much unclear about what you mean. In your previous comment, you mentioned "scheduling batch process with a delay between each job completes". Well, you have control before the the job is executed and after it is executed. It's pretty much difficult to schedule when the jobs are already launched, unless job completes and then you have some control.

Comment: Suppose the api has a limit of 50 requests per second and we have 140 jobs.
As a result, I want to send 50 requests at once, and after a 1-second delay, the next 50 items will be sent, and again a 1-second delay, and so on, until the entire list is complete.
I used to do this easily in Python with the apscheduler library, but now I need to implement it with Vertx

Comment: I've added additional links in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use any out of the box rate limiter function and adapt it for async use.

An example with the `RateLimiter` from Guava:

```java
    // Make permits available at a rate of one every 5 seconds
    private RateLimiter limiter = RateLimiter.create(1 / 5.0);

    // A vert.x future that completes when it obtains a throttle permit
    public Future<Double> throttle() {
        return vertx.executeBlocking(p -> p.complete(limiter.acquire()), true);
    }
```

Then...

```
   throttle()
       .compose(d -> {
           System.out.printf("Waited %.2f before running job\n", d);
           return runJob(); // runJob returns a Future result
       });
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, just a question: dose this limiter affect other program process? or just runJob will be limited with this limiter ?

Comment: I tried to test it but it seems there is syntax error that I could not figure out

Comment: What version of  vert.x are you using?

Comment: ...and what's the syntax error?

Comment: vert.x 3.9.2 and problems: 1-'complete(T)' in 'io.vertx.core.Promise' cannot be applied to '(double)' on `limiter.acquire()` 2-';' expected on `throttle() {` 3- Expression expected on `throttle() {`

Comment: I don't think the promisified version of executeBlocking is available in v3 (example is written against the vert.x version 4.2 api). You'd have to rewrite the `throttle` method with callbacks.